# How to add extra data to a HyperlinkedModelSerializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to add some extra data to my serializer. In my ajax call I am already sending an additional field "message" (Text from a textarea). This field is not in my model.

Bellow is a sample snippet of my code. 
EDIT: This code is working

## views.py

```
class BookingRequestViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = BookingRequestSerializer
```

## serializers.py

```
class BookingRequestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = BookingRequest
        fields = (
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'startdate',
            'enddate',
            'guests',
            'building'
            )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        bookingrequest_obj = super().create(validated_data)

        if 'message' in self.context:
            BookingRequestMessage(
                bookingrequest=bookingrequest_obj,
                message=self.context['request'].data.get('message'),
                sender=BookingRequestMessage.Mieter
            ).save()

        return bookingrequest_obj
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access extra data sent with POST request in Django Rest Framework serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015498/how-to-access-extra-data-sent-with-post-request-in-django-rest-framework-seriali)

Comment: you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47015702/8060120)

Comment: Is it save to store self.context['message'] to the database without any validation?

Comment: no you use it in wrong way, you should `self.context['request'].data.get('message')` please read docs.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my code and it is also working. Thank you

Comment: glad to help you